# How do I add a custom key to PHP in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, key, field

I am attempting to make a custom query in Wordpress.  I want to have it pull up any posts that are tagged relevant to the page that people are on.  IE - If they are on the Bay 198 Skatepark page, they also see a list of all Bay 198 Skatepark posts.

I've gotten the custom query to work, but I need this to be dynamic so that if you are on the Bay 198 page, you see those posts, but if you are on the Precision Skateboards page, you see those specific posts.

The easiest way I could think to accomplish this was to create a custom field on each page that would be the same as the tag and that way I would just fill in the tag for each page as a custom field and it would return the posts.

The issue is that I can't figure out how to implement the custom key call into the custom query.  Here's my code so far, this one being the one that works:

```
<?php $second_query = new WP_Query(' tag=bay-198&posts_per_page=500 '); while( $second_query->have_posts() ) : $second_query->the_post(); ?>
```

I just need to figure out how to replace that "tag=bay-198" and have it dynamically pull in the tag based on the page.

Hopefully that makes sense, I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable that containts the value of your custom field. Then add that variable into the query like so:

```
<?php 
$mykey_values = get_post_custom_values('my_key');
$tag = $mykey_values['your-custom-field'];
$second_query = new WP_Query(' tag=' . $tag . '&posts_per_page=500 '); while( $second_query->have_posts() ) : $second_query->the_post(); ?>
```

Comment: This is the right idea, the only problem is that I need it to be dynamic so that I can place the code into the template and then it will just register whatever the custom key is on the page.